# Implement finally in PHP 5.5 and below

Tags: php, php-5.3

Is there a way to implement a finally block for PHP versions below 5.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this,

```
try {
   # ...
} catch (Exception $e) {
   # ... but don't re- throw $e!
}

# ... finally ...

if (isset ($e)) {
    throw $e;
}
```

But, I should recommend to upgrade PHP. It shouldn't be that hassle.